# CloudKit share with users that don't have app installed

Tags: cloudkit

I need to share a record with contacts that don't yet have my app installed.  I know there's a way to direct the recipient of the share invitation to the app store where they can download my app.... for some reason i haven't been able to figure out how to do it.  Currently, with my app, if the recipient doesn't have my app, the are instructed to "Turn on iCloud . you need to turn on icloud for "my app" before you can open it".  Since they don't have the app, this will send them into a state of confusion and despair.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your `CKShare`, you can set the default **`publicPermission`** to **`.readWrite`** so that people only need the link to your share in order to get started using the shared record. Here's an example:

```
//:: Step 1 :: Create the rootRecord and share
let rootRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "...", recordID: CKRecordID(recordName: "...", zoneID: "..."))

let share = CKShare(rootRecord: rootRecord)

share[CKShareTitleKey] = "..." as CKRecordValue
share[CKShareTypeKey] = "com.example.YourApp" as CKRecordValue
share.publicPermission = .readWrite //<-- This is the important part

//:: Step 2:: Save the share to CloudKit
let operation = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: [rootRecord, share], recordIDsToDelete: nil)
operation.savePolicy = .changedKeys
operation.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = { records, recordIDs, error in
    if let error = error{
      print(error)
    }else{
      if let url = share.url{
        //:: Step 3 :: Grab the share URL
        print(url.absoluteString) //<-- Save this URL somewhere that you can send to people
      }
    }
}
```

With this `publicPermission` level, you don't need a `CKUserIdentity` to add a participant. You can add them later when they start using your app.

See the [publicPermission docs here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckshare/1640494-publicpermission) for more details.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your feed back. I was actually asking about how to include an app store link to my app for those recipients that don't have my app installed.  I have been able to send the invitation to one and all.  If the recipient has my app installed, it will launch my app fine.  If they don't have the app i'd like it to bring them to the app store when they tap on the invitation.    Do you have any insights?